# What is the best way to join two tables using models in Gorm?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am stuck into joining two tables using GORM. After all research I found that preload will solve the issue. However, I am not getting clearly on how to use it. I tried a lot of ways but none worked. I have two table. User and Role. Each user will be associated with one role.

Here is the schema for user table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `app_id` int NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `verifications` json DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'A json Object in a specific format.\n{\n Verification_Code : {\n       isCompleted: Bool,\n       message: "Some custom message",\n      extraInfo: {}\n  }\n}',
  `role_id` int NOT NULL,
  `status` int NOT NULL COMMENT '0 = Good Status and active account\n> 0 = Bad Status and deactive account',
  `company_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`email`,`app_id`),
  KEY `role_key_colmn_idx` (`role_id`),
  KEY `app_key_column_idx` (`app_id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `app_key_column` FOREIGN KEY (`app_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `role_key_colmn` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companies` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Schema for Role Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_id` int NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code_UNIQUE` (`code`),
  KEY `App_Id_conn_idx` (`app_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `App_Id_conn` FOREIGN KEY (`app_id`) REFERENCES `applications` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

User Entity model:

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName     string `gorm:"column:first_name;not_null"`
    LastName      string `gorm:"column:last_name;not_null"`
    Email         string `gorm:"column:email;not_null"`
    Password      string `gorm:"column:password;not_null"`
    AppId         uint   `gorm:"column:app_id;not_null"`
    Verifications string `gorm:"column:verifications;not_null"`
    Status        int    `gorm:"column:status;not_null"`
    Role          Role
    Company       Company
}

func (User) TableName() string { return "users" }
```

Role Entity Model:

```
type Role struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"column:name;not_null"`
    Description string `gorm:"column:description"`
    AppId uint `gorm:"column:app_id;not_null"`
    Code string `gorm:"column:code;not_null;"`
}

func (Role) TableName() string { return "roles" }
```

This is the query that I am using:

```
err := r.db.Where(&Entity.User{AppId: appId, Email: username, Password: password}).Take(&u).Error;
```

This is populating User info but not role info. Any help will be really appreciated. In spring boot it used to automatically populate by setting some @annotations but here I am not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add the foreign key field in the model itself and specify the column name in the field tag unless you're using the [default](http://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#Foreign-Key) GORM naming convention for the foreign key column. Then you need to add the gorm field tag for the foreign key on the referenced model `gorm:"foreignkey:RoleId"`

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName     string `gorm:"column:first_name;not_null"`
    LastName      string `gorm:"column:last_name;not_null"`
    Email         string `gorm:"column:email;not_null"`
    Password      string `gorm:"column:password;not_null"`
    AppId         uint   `gorm:"column:app_id;not_null"`
    Verifications string `gorm:"column:verifications;not_null"`
    Status        int    `gorm:"column:status;not_null"`
    Role          Role   `gorm:"foreignkey:RoleId"`
    RoleId        int
    Company       Company
}
```

Then to eager load the Role you can use [Preload](http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html)

`err := r.db.Preload('Role').Where(&Entity.User{AppId: appId, Email: username, Password: password}).Take(&u).Error;`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I just like to clarify something here. So behind the scene gorm foreignkey tag on Role will look `RoleId` and do the JOIN query right? Another question is instead of using string in preload, can I specify role object there? And last question is if I dont want to use RoleID and just use Role the column name in sql have to be RoleId or something else?

Comment: 1. Yes, GORM will join based on the property specified in the foreign key tag, in this case is RoleId which is mapped to the column role_id column.

2. Preload accepts string, to get the preloaded object you can access it from the property of the object you're fetching. The string 'Role' in preload refers to the property defined in the User object, not the name of the 'Role' model.

Comment: 3. You still need to define the foreign key property regardless of whether or not you're using the default naming convention. The only difference is if you use RoleID, you can omit the ````gorm:"foreignkey:RoleId"```` . If you want to omit RoleId from json you can use the field tag ```json:"-"```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much